# Is it possible to run jar files using different versions of java?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, java, powerpc

So, we are running hadoop on a Power PC machine (64 bit). It runs using the IBM JDK. However, within that hadoop map reduce program, different processes are spawned (using the ProcessBuilder class) which execute jar programs. The problem is that those programs have problem running with IBM JDK's virtual machine and therefore require Open JDK. Likewise hadoop has problem running with the OpenJDK on the Power PC. So I was wondering, if its possible to execute a jar file using a different version of java. So, for example, in this case, the hadoop uses the IBM JDK and the jar files that are executed within the map reduce program use Open JDK. Basically, we need to use different java virtual machines for programs running simultaneously.

Comment: What prevents the programs from using the IBM JDK and how are the jar processes spawned from hadoop ?

Comment: Well I don't really know, but the program I am running is known to crash with IBM JDK. The processes are spawned within the map reduce program using the ProcessBuilder class in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the most important bits of information in your comment - the spawning via the `ProcessBuilder` class. This class makes calls on OS level, so you can start any process with this, and they are completely separate from the Java process that started them. So the general answer is "yes, this is possible". Just make sure the `ProcessBuilder` calls a different Java installation.

Comment: Do you know how to call a different Java installation using the ProcessBuilder class? I mean, by using which method and arguments?

Comment: The ProcessBuilder just makes a call on _system_ level. Just include the full path to the "other" Java installation in the call.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java versions are just a link to the related installation directories. So when you install the various (downloads are here:`http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html`) then you just need to change the link (`ln -s`) to that subdirectory.  For example we kept 4 versions of java on systems:

```
/usr/java/java_7_64bt
/usr/java/java_7_32bt
/usr/java/java_6_64bt
/usr/java/java_6_32bt
# ls -l /usr/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Aug  5 15:00 /usr/bin/java ->  /usr/java/java_7_64bit/java
```

Other programs can then just call either the `/usr/bin/java` or the direct path of the versions that need while hadoop calls something else.